# How to load all users usernames in parse database ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have tried this, to get the first users username.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
NSArray *users = [query findObjects];
_username.text = users[0];
```

But I am just getting an error:

'-[PFUser copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17816cd80'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set a PFUser object in an NSString.

Try this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
NSArray *users = [query findObjects];
_username.text = users[0][@"username"];
```

This will set _username.text to the username field of the first PFUser in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in swift2.0

```
func findAllUsernames(){

    let query = PFUser.query()

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in



        if error == nil {

            if objects?.count > 0{

                var arr = [String]()

                for obj in objects!{

                    arr.append(obj["Username"] as! String)



                }

                print(SharedManager.sharedInstance.allBitUserNames)

            }



        }

    }

}



}
```